# Auth error:Error: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

got an error while trying to run google-tts-api(Google cloud platform) for a node.js application. How can I fix this error ?
Help would be greatly appreciated !

> Auth error:Error: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences between systems.